# How do I get textarea for Html.EditorForModel() method in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

Somebody knows the answer? I'm using L2S with field ntext in my db

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your model, you need to specify the a [DataType.MultilineText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype(VS.100).aspx) annotation:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string MyProperty;
```